# Как парсить и скачать картинки с сайта?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, bs4

Мне нужно спарсить картинку а точнее .gif и скачать ее, а если так нельзя то спарсить ее URL или путь к ней.

Код:

```html
<div class="media-container1"><div class="media-container2"><picture>
<source srcset="https://i.gifer.com/origin/d0/d0fc7bdc9a240be0950efb47f3c90f81_w200.webp" type="image/webp">
<source srcset="https://i.gifer.com/origin/d0/d0fc7bdc9a240be0950efb47f3c90f81_w200.gif" type="image/gif">
<img alt="Загрузка гифка - Загрузка GIF" class="preview-media preview-media_loaded" src="https://i.gifer.com/origin/d0/d0fc7bdc9a240be0950efb47f3c90f81_w200.gif" role="presentation">
</picture></div>
</div>
```

Мой парсер:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get("https://gifer.com/ru/gifs/loading")
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
img = soup.find('picture', class_='preview-media preview-media_loaded')

print(img)
```

Comment: Хорошо было бы увидеть вашу попытку написать код парсера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не работал код, т.к. при загрузке страницы там нет нужных вам тегов, а те теги подгружаются динамически при выполнении [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

У `BeautifulSoup` нет скриптового движка, поэтому он не будет выполнять код на странице. Вам нужно использовать ту библиотеку, у которой будет поддержка [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), например [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium).

*[Тут я накидал простенький пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/1605eb9e4c2cd9dd019a46b53031a1cadb36e4c9/html_parsing/gifer_com__ru__gifs__loading.py#L17), но хочу заметить, что вам скорее всего придется его дописывать, т.к. гифки на том сайте тоже динамически подгружаются при прокручивании страницы вниз. В моем примере есть один скролл вниз, чтобы показать как это выглядит, а делать полную прогрузку всех гифок не буду (но тут у меня есть [пример скролла для яндекс-плейлиста](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/97063d53f0b79eee5b4132c1ecaae7b13708cc58/selenium__examples/music_yandex_ru/get_all_tracks_playlist/variant_2_with_scroll_optimization.py#L49), можете с него пример брать).*

Для установки [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) выполнить команду (для `Firefox` [нужно будет еще скачать](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/cf2c2b69c1886d7df68fa07ac4e2782c19f228eb/selenium__examples/hello_world.py#L18) `geckodriver.exe`):

```
pip install selenium
```

Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


def get_urls(driver):
    urls = []

    for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('figure.media-thumb.desktop link[itemprop=contentUrl]'):
        url_gif = link.get_attribute('content')
        gif_id = url_gif.split('/')[-1]
        url_download = URL_DOWNLOAD_TEMPLATE + gif_id
        urls.append(url_download)

    return urls


URL_DOWNLOAD_TEMPLATE = 'https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/'


options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://gifer.com/ru/gifs/loading')

driver.implicitly_wait(20)

urls = get_urls(driver)
print(f'{len(urls)}: {urls}')
# 4: ['https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/g0R5.gif', 'https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/VAyR.gif', 'https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/ZKZx.gif', 'https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/ZZ5H.gif']

# Small scroll down
driver.execute_script(f'window.scrollTo(0, 200);')

urls = get_urls(driver)
print(f'{len(urls)}: {urls}')
# 8: ['https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/g0R5.gif', 'https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/VAyR.gif', 'https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/ZKZx.gif', 'https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/ZZ5H.gif', 'https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/g0R9.gif', 'https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/ZWdx.gif', 'https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/7pld.gif', 'https://i.gifer.com/embedded/download/AqCa.gif']

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Для вашего примера:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="media-container1"><div class="media-container2"><picture><source srcset="https://i.gifer.com/origin/d0/d0fc7bdc9a240be0950efb47f3c90f81_w200.webp" type="image/webp"><source srcset="https://i.gifer.com/origin/d0/d0fc7bdc9a240be0950efb47f3c90f81_w200.gif" type="image/gif"><img alt="Загрузка гифка - Загрузка GIF" class="preview-media preview-media_loaded" src="https://i.gifer.com/origin/d0/d0fc7bdc9a240be0950efb47f3c90f81_w200.gif" role="presentation"></picture></div></div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
img = soup.find('img', class_='preview-media')
img_url = img['src']
```

даст в img_url адрес гифки: https://i.gifer.com/origin/d0/d0fc7bdc9a240be0950efb47f3c90f81_w200.gif

Comment: Попробовал ваш код с ссылкой автора и `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` в `img_url = img['src']`. Код: `r = requests.get("https://gifer.com/ru/gifs/loading")` + `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')`

Comment: @Jack_oS Спасибо, код работает, но можно сделать так чтобы он парсил сразу несколько картинок с сайта, например первые 10